# Different terminal ids in ps and tty

Tags: bash, tty, ps

The proccess I've started has a different terminal id from tty result. Is there some rule for that? Is there a way to find out what terminal id would programms have if I started them?

```
user@machine:~> tty
/dev/pts/1
user@machine:~> ps -e | grep mc
3761 pts/0    00:00:00 mc
```

I'm connected to an openSUSE 11.3 machine via putty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `mc` allocated another tty for the spawned `tty` process. Guess you'll have a better luck without `mc`.